# Android Java Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field newcommon

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-studio

I'm new for Java, I have code like this

```
private static final String URL= "http://yahoo.com";
```

and I want to make the yahoo to dynamic text from edittext

```
<EditText
       android:id="@+id/url"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:hint="@string/add_account_blog_url"
       android:inputType="textUri" />

EditText url = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.url); 
String newcommon = (String)url.getText().toString();
private static final String URL= newcommon;
```

Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field `newcommon`.

when I try to make

```
private static final string
```

to

```
private string
```

The apps get crash. So the question is, How to make static to a dynamic? I want to put variable in private static or how to change private static to somethings simillar but it wont cause the apps crash?

Comment: I assume you know the difference between static and instance members. Check all the places where that variable is used. If it is used anywhere in a static context, keep it static, if it is not, and you need to access it in a static member, create a local instance and call the value

Comment: You can try initializing it in a `static` block maybe. I don't know much about them and what is allowed inside them, but it's worth a shot.

Comment: Stultuske : the problem is, it a ton java in this source apps. i can't check it manually. but will try if have to.

Zar : yeah. good idea. can you give some simple code? im new for java

Answer (score 0):

In Java,

**static** : When a variable is declared with the keyword “static”, its called a “class variable”. All instances share the same copy of the variable. A class variable can be accessed directly with the class, without the need to create a instance.

- Use : When you want to declare a variable, value of which is operated by all objects then you can use this.

**final** : If you make any variable as final, you cannot change the value of final variable(It will be constant).

- Use : When you want to define a field, value of which can not be changed.

Now we use static and final both together in which variable that we want to use for every object of that class and do not allow to change value of it.

```
private static final String URL= newcommon;
```

Here, You are assigning a value to final field, So Compiler will give an error.
Use local variable here.

Change your code to

```
EditText url = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edt_test);
        String newcommon = (String)url.getText().toString();
        String newURL=YourClass.URL+newcommon;
```

And you want to use this variable anywhere else then pass this variable there.
This is conventional practices.

Comment: i heard what you saying, but i can't express the coding. can you give me simple code for example?

Comment: @sailornoob : What you want to do exactly? you want to attach string in edittext at end of Yahoo url ?

Comment: yeah, i wanna create own wordpress android apps. and i get the source from http://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/ios-android-retirement/. and it only load static wordpress url. check this code http://pastebin.com/6x7EacMA.

Comment: i know. thats why i ask with different situation.